# Implementation of Hellinger distance with numpy only

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, matrix

I got this task to implement a python function using NumPy.
The function should compute the [Hellinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance) distance between two matrices `P` and `Q` with dimensions `(n, k)`. `p_i` is the vector of row `i` of `P` and `p_i,j` is the value of row `i` in column `j` of `P`.

The Hellinger distance for matrices is defined as followed:

```
h_i = i/sqrt(2) * sqrt(sum(j=1,k) of (sqrt(p_i,j)-sqrt(q_i,j))^2)
```

`H` is a vector of length `n` and `h_i` is the value `i` of `H`, with `i = 1,...,n`. So the Hellinger distance between two matrices is equivalent to the Hellinger distance between the rows of the matrices. For each row, the distance is stored in the output vector `H`.

The task now is to implement the function (using NumPy), which will compute the above-described problem. It gets handed over two 2D-NumPy-Arrays `P` and `Q`, and it should return a 1D-Numpy-Array `H` of the right length.

I never worked with NumPy before, so I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

I informed myself a little bit on the [NumPy-Docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.math.html) but I would love to get any suggentions.

Comment: Since you've seen the docs already I'd say give it a try yourself and come back when/if you get stuck. The formula seems to be rather straight forward without any very complicated parts, so no very numpy specific knowledge is needed, just array operations

Comment: Check this out: https://gist.github.com/larsmans/3116927

Comment: Also this: https://nbviewer.org/gist/Teagum/460a508cda99f9874e4ff828e1896862

Comment: The formula only computes one value (it iterates over one row of Q and P). My problem is that I don't understand how to get all values (essentially all rows of Q and P) in one output array H, without using a for loop. Is there a way to do that with NumPy? (It's probably trivial but I'm a complete beginner in NumPy)

Comment: @СергейКох I don't have much code yet because I'm struggling to understand how NumPy is processing 2D-arrays. For example: When I'm trying `np.sqrt(1/2) * np.sqrt(  np.sum((np.sqrt(P) - np.sqrt(Q))**2) )` it returns a scalar not a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that you need to use the `axis` argument in certain NumPy functions (e.g. `np.sum()`) in order to tell NumPy if it should iterate over the rows or columns of an array. I did exactly that: `return np.sqrt(1/2) * np.sqrt(  np.sum((np.sqrt(P) - np.sqrt(Q))**2,axis=1) )` and it works.

The only problem is that it still gives back negative values. How is that possible, since the subtraction is taken to the power of 2?